# Can the "new book" tag be restored in iBooks (iOS)

Tags: ios, books

I'm wondering if is possible to restore the "new book" tag that you can see on the top right corner of the new books uploaded or bought within iBooks (iOS) (visible on the following image)

[image]

My use case, is that often I upload a book in whatever format I have it and checks if it has been uploaded fine, however as soon as it was opened for the first time the "new tag" vanishes and since this is still a book I will read I would like to restore the tag.

Does any of you know if there is a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only purpose of the "New" tag is to show books that have never been opened. Once a book has been viewed, it is no longer New.

Maybe with enough feedback Apple will add a "Reading" tag to the icon...